# Determining coin combinations in python

Tags: python

I was asked to write a program in python that will correctly find the combination of coins, and the amount of each coin, in a given amount of money. In this problem only nickels and dimes are used.

Ex - Given that there are 10 coins, how many nickels and dimes are in $.85?

This is how I solved it:

1. Set up equations:

   d + n = 10
   .10d + .05n = .85
2. Solve for n:
   n = 10 - d
3. Solve:
   .10d + .05(10-d) = .85
   .05d + .5 -.05d = .85
   .05d = .35
   d = 7
   n = 3

How would I go about programming this?

Sorry if this is a stupid question but Im pretty new to python and I'm completely lost on this one.

Comment: You'll need to provide `some` code. You'll learn more by trying. Maybe a good Python tutorial (google Dive into Python) can help.

Comment: Do you have any experience of programming? (any language)

Comment: *.05d + .5 -.05d = .85* nope, no matter what `d` is, it will always be 0.5. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Let the number of coins be `a`, so `d + n = a`.

Let the sum be `b`, so `0.1d + 0.05n = b`.

Then

```
n = a - d
0.1d+0.05(a-d)=b
0.05d = b-0.05a
d = 20b - a
n = a - d = a - 20b +a = 2a - 20b
```

So, given `a` and `b`:

```
d = 20b - a
n = a - d
```

Now we just need to program these 2 formulae in Python.

Look at the examples in the official docs: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

```
def count(num, total_sum):
    d = 20*total_sum - num
    n = num - d
    return (n,d)

print count(10, 0.85)
```

Comment: +1 for the use of algebra to reduce the solution into quick computations, rather than looping structures.

Answer (score 2):

No points for style, but a simple search of all possibilities is quick to write and fast enough for practical purposes. Just start with all nickels, no dimes, then keep adding one to dimes and removing one from nickels until you get the answer (or don't).

```
def solve(ncoins, cents):
    nickels = ncoins
    dimes = 0
    for ii in range(ncoins):
        if (nickels * 5) + (dimes * 10) == cents:
            return "{nickels} nickels, {dimes} dimes".format(
                nickels=nickels, dimes=dimes)
        nickels -= 1
        dimes += 1
    raise AssertionError("{ncoins} coins can't be {cents} cents!".format(
        ncoins=ncoins, cents=cents))

print solve(10, 85)
print solve(10, 75)
print solve(100, 75)
```

output:

```
3 nickels, 7 dimes
5 nickels, 5 dimes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/akg/tmp/sacoins.py", line 16, in <module>
    print solve(100, 75)
  File "/home/akg/tmp/sacoins.py", line 10, in solve
    raise AssertionError("{ncoins} coins can't be {cents} cents!".format(ncoins=ncoins, cents=cents))
AssertionError: 100 coins can't be 75 cents!
```

Comment: You could have used `filter` for doing this.  For example: `filter(lambda x: x[0]*5 + x[1]*10 == 85, enumerate(range(11)[::-1]))` (though this is only shorter).

Answer (score 1):

If you only have dimes and nickels, you can just do the following:

```
>>> total_coins = 10
>>> nickels = 85 / 5  # 85 is the total amount in cents; 5 is the value of a nickel
>>> nickels
17
>>> dimes = 0
>>> while dimes + nickels != total_coins:
...    dimes += 1
...    nickels -= 2
... 
>>> dimes
7
>>> nickels
3
>>>
```

Since there are 2 nickels per dime, you can figure out how many nickels there are and add one to the dimes for each two nickels, until you have the right number of coins.

Comment: If the OP is reading this, go type that out `D K`'s answer half a dozen times, or until it stops looking like a foriegn language.

Answer (score 0):

Or rather than iterate through possible combos of coins, you could use (given total and numcoins as input):

```
justnickels = total/.05 
numdimes = justnickels - numcoins
numnickels = numcoins - numdimes
```

If you get negative numbers as one of the answers, then the particular combo (like .85 composed of 5 coins) is unsolvable.